# What is the relationship between Map Service Instances and SDE connections?

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, gps, map-service, arcgis-mobile

We have a GPS project based on ArcGIS Mobile 10.0. There are two web map services and each were kept as Nonpooled with Minimum instances 15 and maximum instances 60 by original developer. The database is ORACLE and connection is made through SDE. Recently whole enterprise moved to 10.1 except GPS project which has some crashing issues with 10.1. But that led hosting of this GPS project on an old Test server.

Two incidents happened in last two weeks when the connections for GPS projects reached alarming high in few minutes (122 and 58). First time it affected the SDE server and caused total chaos- we had to kill the processes and bounce the SDE server back. Second time, we restarted the services before things out of control. I investigated the first time - only 20 GPS devices were connected that time. I am new to ArcGIS mobile and don't know SDE in detail(It is still under DBA control and I can only investigate the appserver). How will the number of SDE connections being used one time transforms to map services? I want to go to management with the reasons and recommendations.